# Rspec model validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

i try to use TDD Rspec for model validation in rails 3.
my user_spec.rb file look like

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

before { @user = User.new(name: "eric", country: "hawaii", email: "nice@nice.ch", password: "nicenice") }

subject { @user }

it { should respond_to(:name) }
it { should respond_to(:email) }

it { should be_valid }

end
```

after running rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb, i get an error message

```
No DRb server is running. Running in local process instead ...
..F

Failures:

  1) User 
     Failure/Error: it { should be_valid }
     TypeError:
       type mismatch: String given
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:37:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.09495 seconds
3 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:37 # User 

Randomized with seed 42015
```

should be_valid expected a string?

Comment: check your model (user.rb), could be triggered by your validations

Comment: Please edit your question to add the code for your `User` class.

Comment: the errors was in user model. thanks so much for help.